# Exiting application on X button of form pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, modal-dialog, exit

I have a modal form (login) which I want that on closing it using "X" button, force application to exit.
I tried this:

[image]

```
private void Login_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

this cause my application to exit on pressing login button (closing). but I want exiting only on "X" button of window.
How can I do it?

Comment: What is `Login_Deactivate`?  Where is this method, in the login form or elsewhere?  Who/what calls it?

Comment: @DonBoitnott it is deactivate event of my login modal form

Comment: And what triggers this event to fire?

Comment: @DonBoitnott see edited question with image!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `Deactivate` event, you don't need it.

The issue here is that you cannot tell that just the "X" button was pressed.  What you really do is track all the other conditions that cause form close, and react when it's *not* one of those.

You should leverage the `DialogResult` enum, and allow the calling application to react, instead of trying to do it all in the Login form.

In your Login form constructor, set the property to `None`:

```
public Login()
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

Then, in your button handler for "OK", set the property:  `DialogResult = DialogResult.OK`.

If you have a specific Cancel event, you can set `DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel`.

Ultimately, you could have a `FormClosing` event in the Login form, in which you can check this value and react.  But more importantly, your calling application can check the result from the login form and react there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `this.Parent.Application.Exit()`, it kills whole application.

Comment: I want to kill whole application on pressing "X"

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Comment: That's already there in the example.  You're not suggesting anything new.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Deactivate event, subscribe to the "`FormClosing`" event of the "Login" form. Write the same code which you have written.
Keep the `Deactivate` event only if it is required to close the Application when you click outside login form.

Comment: That won't help.  You still will not know _why_ it is closing, and that's the meat of this question.